# Disable filter for related product

Tags: cart, product-relations

As per the answer of pspahn in the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253606/magento-related-products-not-displaying-on-product-page , there is a filter that makes Magento not display the related products when they are already in the cart.

How to disable this filter?

Use case : I am using it for my spare parts and I would like to keep it showing no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filtering is done in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related:_prepareData()`.
These are the lines that do it:

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($this->_itemCollection,
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
);
```

rewrite the block mentioned above and remove those lines.

For EE Version, the file to amend is `Enterprise_TargetRule_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Related:getExcludeProductIds()‌​` and the lines to amend

```
if (is_null($this->_excludeProductIds)) {
        $cartProductIds = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getProductIds();
        $this->_excludeProductIds = array_merge($cartProductIds, array($this->getProduct()->getEntityId()));
    }
```

Comment: OK, so it means : create a module, in that module, get a new function `_prepareData()` that is same as the one from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Related:_prepareData()` except for the lines you mentioned. I think I can do that, thanks

Comment: @Memes. I'm sure you can. :) But don't go alone. Take this as help: http://magedev.com/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/

Comment: Thanks Marius, that helped me a lot. It happened that I have the Enterprise version and then the lines to modify are in `Enterprise_TargetRule_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Related:getExcludeProductIds()` and the line to de-activate are `if (is_null($this->_excludeProductIds)) {
            $cartProductIds = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getProductIds();
            $this->_excludeProductIds = array_merge($cartProductIds, array($this->getProduct()->getEntityId()));
        }`

Comment: @Memes, well, you should have stated that you are working on EE. :)

Comment: I edited your answer with my findings then. and, yes, I should have stated it :)